# XML Serializing Entire Class To String

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

How do I reduce an XML element that represents a class to a single string? My XML serializer outputs this:

```
<ArrayOfCity>
  <City>
    <Name>Los Angeles</Name>
    <Location>
      <Value>034.050N -118.250E</Value>
    </Location>
    <Elevation>305</Elevation>
    <Population>3884000</Population>
  </City>
  <City>
    <Name>New York</Name>
    <Location>
      <Value>040.713N -074.006E</Value>
    </Location>
    <Elevation>33</Elevation>
    <Population>8550405</Population>
  </City>
</ArrayOfCity>
```

But I want it to look like this (simplified `<Location>` element):

```
<ArrayOfCity>
  <City>
    <Name>Los Angeles</Name>
    <Location>034.050N -118.250E</Location>
    <Elevation>305</Elevation>
    <Population>3884000</Population>
  </City>
  <City>
    <Name>New York</Name>
    <Location>040.713N -074.006E</Location>
    <Elevation>33</Elevation>
    <Population>8550405</Population>
  </City>
</ArrayOfCity>
```

My class implementations are:

```vb
Public Class City
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Location As LatLong
    Public Property Elevation As Integer
    Public Property Population As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class

Public Class LatLong
    Implements ISerializable

    <XmlIgnore()>
    Private _Lat As Single
    <XmlIgnore()> 
    Private _Long As Single

    <XmlIgnore()> 
    Public Property Latitude As Single
        Get
            Return _Lat
        End Get
        Set(value As Single)
            _Lat = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlIgnore()> 
    Public Property Longitude As Single
        Get
            Return _Long
        End Get
        Set(value As Single)
            _Long = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0:000.000}N {1:000.000}E", Latitude, Longitude)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            'Pos Value: N & E, Neg Value: S & W
            'Format must be [###.###N ###.###E] (spacing and digits can be variable, but cannot use S or W)
            _Lat = CSng(Split(value, "N")(0))
            _Long = CSng(Split(value.Replace("E", ""), "N")(1))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _Lat = 0
        _Long = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(InitialString As String)
        Value = InitialString
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Value
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal O As String) As LatLong
        Return New LatLong(O)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(O As LatLong) As String
        Return O.ToString
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        With DirectCast(obj, LatLong)
            Return Latitude = .Latitude AndAlso Longitude = .Longitude
        End With
    End Function

    Public Shared Operator =(Left As LatLong, Right As LatLong) As Boolean
        Return Left.Equals(Right)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <>(Left As LatLong, Right As LatLong) As Boolean
        Return Not Left.Equals(Right)
    End Operator

    Protected Sub New(info As SerializationInfo, context As StreamingContext)
        'Value = DirectCast(info.GetValue("props", GetType(String)), String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetObjectData(info As SerializationInfo, context As StreamingContext) Implements ISerializable.GetObjectData
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm pretty sure the key will be in the `Protected Sub New(...)` and the `Public Sub GetObjectData(...)`, but I can't figure it out.  As best if can determine, they're more used for XML element properties.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:
I figured it out.  The LatLong class needs to implement IXmlSerializable and the WriteXML(...) and ReadXML(...) subs need to be implemented like this:

```
Public Sub ReadXml(reader As XmlReader) Implements IXmlSerializable.ReadXml
    Value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString
End Sub

Public Sub WriteXml(writer As XmlWriter) Implements IXmlSerializable.WriteXml
    writer.WriteString(Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: if you only surface location value, you can mark Location as non-serialized `<NonSerialized> Public Property Location As LatLong` and introduce another property that will take `Location.Value`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually had that idea, and it works great.  However, I would like to not need to have two members for each property that is a complex data type.  What I posted is just an example that I developed to communicate the question, but my real project has numerous such classes that can be narrowed to strings and I was looking for a cleaner solution all around.  I would mark this as an answer if it weren't a comment... :)

Comment: Well. Lets see. You can separate serialization logic from API logic. Create a second class called `CitySerialized` and develop a couple of extensions on `City` - `ToSerialized/FromSerialized` and when you need, just call `arrayOfCities.select(function(x) x.ToSerialized())` and serialize that. I mean, I don't know the context under which you do this

Comment: How are you serializing your `City` array to XML?  Since you have marked your types with [`XmlSerializer` attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx) it seems reasonable to guess you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).  Can you confirm please?

Comment: Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(CityArr.GetType)
Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
ser.Serialize(sw, CityArr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LatLong class needs to implement IXmlSerializable and the WriteXML(...) and ReadXML(...) subs need to be implemented like this:

```
Public Sub ReadXml(reader As XmlReader) Implements IXmlSerializable.ReadXml
    Value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString
End Sub

Public Sub WriteXml(writer As XmlWriter) Implements IXmlSerializable.WriteXml
    writer.WriteString(Value)
End Sub
```